# Extracting output from Jmeter response

Tags: jmeter

Sample Request1:
id=abcd&payment=paymentinitiate&ENCID=xyz&TOKENID=1234&APPTYPE=908&Mobile=ext

Sample Response1:

{
"RESPONSECODE": "100",
"TESTID": "200",
"ERRORDESC": "Success",
"DOMAINNAME": "TEST",
"TOTALCOUNT": "4"
}

Like above i need to give 100 requests and will be getting 100 separate responses(separate debug samplers) in Jmeter. I want to extract the value for ERRORDESC and DOMAINNAME available in each response in a separate common output file.

Kindly suggest a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding a [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and using the following code:

```
def counter = ctx.getThreadNum() // if you run 100 requests with 100 users
//def counter = vars.getIteration() if you run 100 requests with 1 user and 100 iterations

def response = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())

new File('response-' + counter + '.txt') << response.ERRORDESC << ',' << response.DOMAINNAME
```

it will generate files `response-0.txt`, `response-1.txt` etc. with the data extracted from each response

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)